# How to store ArrayList of some class using SQLite on Android?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, arraylist, hashtable

I made some class that contain some memeber variables.

And I should to link this class with other class like this :

```
Hashtable<Class1 , ArrayList<Class2>>
```

I want to store this Hashtable in SQLite on Android. I consider serialization, Byte stream, but not sure can it possible to my own class.
Some people said that using JSON object. Are the JSON or XML creation is only solution??

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: You could convert it to a byte array and store it as a BLOB in the database.

Comment: Converting a Hashtable to byte[]? Is that even possible? What would happen to the references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JSON or XML, but if you want to run queries on the database, creating tables would be better. If Class1 and Class2 items are stored in tables, the hashtable corresponds to a junction table with columns like Class1_ID and Class2_ID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about that solution, but class2 is located in ArrayList. Therefore, each class1 element have the variable number of class2. It will be good if class1 linked with one class2, but unfortunately it's not. So I need to think that store the variable number of class2 in one column first.

Comment: That isn't a problem, you can have multiple records for each Class1 item.